# What are typical lengths of chat message and comment in database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to create a column in SQL Server database. Entries for that column will contain messages from chat. Previously such messages has been stored as comments.

My main quetion is:
What is typical text length for **chat message** and **comment**?

By the way:
What would happen if I used *varchar(max)*? How would it impact database size and performance? Is better to use powers of 2 or powers of 10 (e.g. 128 instead of 100) while considering text lengths?

Comment: I don't think there's going to be a "typical" answer because it depends on what sort of "conversations" your system is trying to foster.

Comment: I found a tip from MSDN: _Use varchar(max) when the sizes of the column data entries vary considerably, and the size might exceed 8,000 bytes._

Comment: 'Messages from chat' -> what chat? It is likely that the interface of the chat program(s) determine the max length. You should investigate those. Also, don't ask two questions at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VARCHAR(MAX) has a disadvantage: you can not define an index over this column.

Generally, your application should impose a maximum length for a chat message. How big that limit is depends very much on what the application is used for. But anything more than 1000 byte is probably less a legitimate message but an attempt to disrupt your service.

If your maximum value is a power of 2, or a power of ten or any other value has no influence on the performance as long as the row fits in one (8KB) page.

Comment: To be fair, you would be unlikely to want to index a chat-message, unless you were going to give users the ability to find a message by the first 'n' characters of the message text, which would not be a typical scenario for most chat applications...

Comment: Sure. But it needs to be mentioned, so that people don't start using VARCHAR(MAX) everywhere.

Comment: Agreed - I just wanted to clarify it a little :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - it doesn't matter.

From [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx):

> The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes.

So VARCHAR(10) and VARCHAR(10000) will consume the same amount of data if the values don't exceed 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use `N/VARCHAR(MAX)`, it can grow to be 2GB (if I remember correctly). It will grow as required though, so it is very efficient with regards to space unless you are only storing very small amounts of data.